# GIT Auto Merge : Injects or deletes codes without user knowledge

Tags: git

I was trying to rebase my GIT stream and found that some auto merging happened during rebase:

```
$ git rebase origin/develop
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
--------------------------------------------------
warning: 2 lines add whitespace errors.
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       repo1
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging test/Fake.hpp
Removing test/Test.hpp
Auto-merging repo2
CONFLICT (submodule): Merge conflict in repo1
```

I was doing a code review changes incorporation where in file test/Fake.hpp a line content needed to be modified from **XXXXyyyZZZ to XXXXZZZ** - but after checking in the changes and during rebase it got changed back to **XXXXyyyZZZ** ?

It is a big issue for me as I am not sure what auto merges has taken place and how can I protect from it or know at least what changes are being made as auto merge?

Comment: The rebase was interrupted by conflict. Fix it, add the changes, and run `git rebase --continue` to finish the rebase. After that, see if the file content is as expected.

Comment: I did that but saw that file content was changed

Comment: What do you mean "without user's knowledge". You should be aware what it's merging.

Comment: Auto merge is what I mean without user's knowledge. I assume that merge is complete but it has silently changed content of my file - I am assuming that the file in local is what is in BASE plus modified content by me -  I have seen other scenarios also - Checkin Changes - push to VSTS - again modify same file as per details provided above - commit and rebase - the changes made currently will be overwritten by auto merge